# How to find particular text after convert HTML to text in azure logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, text-extraction, email-body

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="Generator" content="Amazon WorkMail v3.1.358.0"></head><body><table class="Table" width="909" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:909px"><tbody><tr><td style="background-color:#d9e1f2; border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Type</span></span></span></p></td><td style="background-color:#d9e1f2; border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Detail</span></span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Bot ID</span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">4122</span></span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Bot Name </span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Route U2K2 -CR </span></span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:38px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Bot Overview </span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:38px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">BOT to process all the SR's raised in remedy for Route U2K2. </span></span></span></p></td><td style="height:38px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Stakeholder/Business approver Name </span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><u><span style="color:#0563c1"><a href="mailto:Ellen.Daniel@unilever.com" style="color:#0563c1; text-decoration:underline">someemail.com</a></span></u></span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Estimated Run Costs</span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">&nbsp;</span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:315px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif"><span style="color:black">Margin (Euros) - Optional </span></span></span></p></td><td style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:none; height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:215px"><p><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif">&nbsp;</span></span></p></td><td style="height:19px; padding:0cm 7px 0cm 7px; width:64px">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

email body is in html converted to text like below, I need to find the required data and place those data somewhere.

How to split and take particular required text.

The logic app design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3AF.png

email body image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k89j.png

the data was not in key value pair

```
Detail

Bot ID

4122

Bot Name 

Route U2K2 -CR 

Bot Overview 

BOT to process all the SR's raised in remedy for Route U2K2. 

Stakeholder/Business approver Name
```

Comment: Could you please give us an example to tell us what you want to get? For example, do you want to get the `Bot ID` in the text?

Comment: thankyou, i need to get  4122, Route U2K2 -CR, BOT to process all the SR's raised in remedy for Route U2K2.  like this information.

Comment: i have added email body image above

Comment: What did the html look like before conversion?

Comment: Jack, I have attached html how it look for the emailbody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting html to text, you can use `substring('<text>', <startIndex>, <length>)` to get the value you want.

Before you use `substring('<text>', <startIndex>, <length>)`, you need to get `<startIndex>`and `<length>` first.

**To get startIndex**

You can use `indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID')` to get the index of `Bot ID`, then use `add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6)` to get the index behind `Bot ID`.

**To get length**

You can use `indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot Name')` to get the index of `Bot Name`, then use `sub(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot Name'),add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6))` to get the length.

The expression like this:

```
substring(variables('var'),add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6),sub(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot Name'),add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6)))
```

The design is like this:

[image]

I did a test:

[image]

**Note**

The text has `\n` to start a newline, so you need to adjust the value of the `startIndex` and `length` according to your own text.

Comment: For example, `indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID')`-1 means that there is no string matching `Bot ID`, please check whether the entered `Bot ID` is correct(Such as the case of characters).

Comment: Perfect Answer! substring(variables('var'),add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6),sub(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot Name'),add(indexOf(variables('var'),'Bot ID'),6)))
   working as per expected

Comment: this is exactly working fine, problem arising to finding the very last element since we dont have next element to extract. you suugestion might help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a full answer, but it may get you started.

As [you can see here,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference), ALA supports xpath and has an xml parser built it. If you can use that, it will make everything much easier and avoid the need to convert and extract. As far as I can tell, ALA doesn't have an html parser.

The problem is that the html you posted is not a valid xml. For example, the `<meta>` nodes aren't closed and the whole thing doesn't have a root node. If these are fixed and you have a valid xml, using the templates in that link can easily output what you need.

For example

```
xpath([your valid xmlstring],'//tr/td[./p//span[./text()="Bot Name "]]/following-sibling::td/p//span[@style="color:black"]/text()')
```

should output:

```
Route U2K2 -CR
```

Similarly,

```
xpath([your valid xmlstring],'//tr/td[./p//span[./text()="Bot Overview "]]/following-sibling::td/p//span[@style="color:black"]/text()')
```

should output:

```
BOT to process all the SR's raised in remedy for Route U2K2.
```

etc.  As I said, not a complete answer...

Comment: but how can to convert  email body to XML

Comment: every time new email arrive for the same above temple, where only data change how to design the logic app from  email body data to convert XML

Comment: @Sandhya As a first step, try running the email as is and see what happens. Sometimes slightly invalid xml can get through.

Comment: possible to provide any example ?